# AngularJs cannot see updated value of input and setting ng-invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Datepicker gets date and puts it into `input` field. Input marked as `required` but AngularJS cannot see changes and mark it as valid. Why?

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': myForm.inputDatetimeStart.$invalid }">
    <label for="datetimepicker_start" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Start date and time: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input class="form-control" name="inputDatetimeStart" ng-model="datetime_start" id="datetimepicker_start" type="text" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 angular.module('myApp', ['ajoslin.promise-tracker', 'ngRoute'])
     .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $log, promiseTracker, $timeout){
       jQuery('#datetimepicker_start').datetimepicker({   });
       ...

     }
```

Comment: Because what the jQuery datepicker is doing when it updates the input box is not "seen" by Angular.  If you want it to work correctly, you should create a directive that wraps the jQuery datetimepicker functionality and then sends the proper events and/or scope $applys when the jQuery datepicker library does something

Comment: Can you please provide example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
$scope.$watch('datetime_start', function () { 
    $scope.$apply();
})
```

it will make a digest cycle occur.